# MySQL "MATCH ... AGAINST" : needle in every column?

Tags: mysql, match, against

I got a problem using MATCH ... AGAINST. Here's a sample table called 'elts'

```
id  |  tags  |  title  |  description
----------------------------------------------
1   |  music |  music  |  music description
2   |  test  |  test   |  music description
```

Here's my query :

```
SELECT id, 
FROM elts
WHERE (tags, title, description) AGAINST ('music')
```

My problem is that I get 2 different results depending on the environment I'm using :

- Wamp (MySQL : 5.6.12) : I get IDs 1 and 2
- 1&1 Server (MySQL : 5.0) : I get only ID 1

On my server, the needle (here 'music') must be present in every column, else the relevance is 0...

Has somebody encountered this problem ?

**EDIT**, table definition :

```
CREATE TABLE elts (
    id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    title VARCHAR(200),
    tags TEXT,
    notes TEXT,
    description TEXT,
    state INT DEFAULT 1,
    creation_date DATETIME,
    modification_date DATETIME,
    FULLTEXT (tags,title,description)
) ENGINE = MYISAM;
```

Comment: Are the table structure (index definitions) and the data set **exactly** the same on both servers?

Comment: Yes, I've used a dump of the first one.

Comment: Please post your table definition.

Comment: it could be also server  charset difference...

Comment: Nice try ! There where indeed 2 different charset... But once I've fixed it, my problem was still there...